# Need help in understanding mathematics formula

Tags: optimization, notation

When I learned some optimization materials. I faced the following formula.

$|F| > \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\binom{n}{i}}$

I know that the left-hand side is a number. So what is the right-hand side. Can anyone explain to me? 
The formula is taken from the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauer%E2%80%93Shelah_lemma

[image: wiki]

Comment: The right hand side is also a number.

Comment: i know. but what is the meaning of the RHS

Comment: @ThắngVũ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: The $\Sigma$ sign (capital Greek sigma) is a shorthand for sum.  The RHS is the sum of terms, indexed by $i$ starting with 0 going up through $k-1$, where each term is a binomial coefficient $\binom n i$.  The whole thing is pronounced "The sum, as $i=0$ through $i=k-1$, of the binomial coefficient $n$ choose $i$.)  Each term is a number, so the sum of these $k$ terms is a number, too.

Comment: thank you. i got it :D

Comment: Specifically, the right hand side _represents_ the number of ways of choosing fewer than $k$ things from a set of $n$ things (including the one way that it's possible to choose $0$ things from a set of $n$ things).